# Persisting notebook on HDInsight cluster

Tags: github, bitbucket, azure-hdinsight

Is there a way to configure HDInsight so I can persist a Jupyter notebook to a bitbucket (or github) repository?

Comment: I am assuming you are currently using notebook which you can access through cluster dashboard. right? I think its possible to [configure Jupyter notebooks on your local machine to connect to HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-install-locally). You can just sync locally created notebooks to your favorite code repository